# How to manage annotation based Hibernate versioning for time stamp column in which value generated by DB

Tags: java, hibernate, optimistic-locking

We can generate version column's value by using below tag in our hbm file:

```xml
<timestamp column="MODIFICATION_DATE"
           name="modificationDate"
           access="property"
           unsaved-value="undefined"
           source="db"
           generated="always"/>
```

What is the corresponding hibernate notation to generate value for time stamp column which date type?

```
private java.util.Date modificationDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the appropriate JPA annotations to achieve the desired result, for example, as follows:

```
@Version
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date modificationDate;
```

Please note:

> An entity may access the state of its version field or property or export a method for use by the application to access the version, but must not modify the version value[34]. With the exception noted in section 4.10, only the persistence provider is permitted to set or update the value of the version attribute in the object.
>
> The version attribute is updated by the persistence provider runtime when the object is written to the database. All non-relationship fields and properties and all relationships owned by the entity are included in version checks[35].
>
> [34] Bulk update statements, however, are permitted to set the value of version attributes. See section 4.10.
>
> [35] This includes owned relationships maintained in join tables.
>
> — [JSR 338: Java™ Persistence 2.1, Final Release](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr338/index.html), page 90.